# Conditional Substitute in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, substitution

I am importing a csv from another website where the data may have either "-" or "-090".
I need to only substitute those rows where the row has ONLY "-",
Is it possible in google sheets?

Currently I have substituted with "-0" then adding a value function before it

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE('live data'!C3:C,"-","-0")),))
```

IS there a simpler way to achieve the same?

Thanks all in advance

Comment: It is unclear whether the data is always like `123-` and `123-090` or like `123-321` and `xyz-123-090-321-090-xyz`, or something else. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: @doubleunary the data always has "-" in first occurrance, so sometimes its only "-" or sometimes "-090" but never "123-" or "123-090" etc

Answer (score 1):

If your data consists of the two values `-` and `-090` only, your can replace the former values with blanks like this:

`=arrayformula( if( 'live data'!C3:C = "-", iferror(1/0), 'live data'!C3:C ) )`

If your data is text strings like `-xxxx` and `-090xxxx`, try `regexreplace()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( if( isblank(C2:C), iferror(1/0), regexreplace('live data'!C3:C, "^-([^0]|$)", "$1") ) )`